# Spring Boot 2 working on embedded Tomcat, but not on external Tomcat

Tags: tomcat9, spring-boot-2

I created a spring boot 2 app and when i run it on my IDE (intelliJ) it works perfectly, but when i try to deploy it to an external tomcat (tomcat version 9.0.80) it doesn't work.

When i run it on my IDE and access localhost:8080/projeto it shows me the page its supposed to show and i can navigate from there on to the other pages and do the things the webapp is meant to do. But when it runs on an external tomcat , i get an "`java.lang.IllegalStateException`" error caused by:

```bash
"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [io.xxx.xxxx.MainApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource cannot be cast to org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource"
```

I think this is because the jar package dependency I introduced conflicts with tomcat. But I don't know how to troubleshoot this error. Because another project has introduced the same versions of "`org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.3`" and "`org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.3`", it can successfully run on external tomcat. (`org.springframework.web.content.support.ServletContextResource` from "`org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.3`", `org.springframework.core.io. ClassPathResource` from "`org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.3`").

I want to know how to troubleshoot such problems.

Comment: I think more stack trace is required to diagnose this.